# I want to create image by passing list of tuple in python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

from PIL  import Image

img=Image.open("Car.jpg")

array= np.array(img)

a = array

rgb=250,0,0

for  i  in  range(768):
      for  j  in  range(500):
             a[ i ] [ j ]=rgb

new_image=Image.fromarray(array)

new_image.save( "new.jpg" )

new_image.show()
```

## I want to pass rgb values like list of tuple :

```
rgb = [(255,0,0),
(198, 252, 247), (255, 255, 250) ,(254, 253, 248) ,(251, 252, 246), (247, 248, 240) ... 
(100, 144, 247), (255, 200, 250), (254, 253,0)]
```

and rgb value change with i  and  j

```
a [ i ] [ j ] = rgb
```

Comment: what would the length of this `rgb` list be? aka how many tuples are being passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("Car.jpg")
rgb = 250,0,0
for i in range(768):
    for j in range(500):
        im.putpixel((i, j), rgb)
img = img.convert("RGB") 
img.save("new.jpg")
img.show()
```

Did you mean this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can get RGB by using **getdata()**. Then you can manipulate each pixel freely. For example, you want to flip an image.

```
from PIL import Image

# Resize for minimising pixels
width, height = 300, 200
src_image = ImageCall('cat.jpg').get_img()
src_image = src_image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# Get pixels in a list
pixels = list(src_image.getdata())
pixels = list(map(lambda i: i[::-1], pixels[:])) # Flipping
# pixels = [(r,g,b), (r,g,b), (r,g,b), (r,g,b), ..... n]

# Add new pixels to construct a new image
dst_image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
dst_image.putdata(pixels)  # Place pixels in the new image.
dst_image.save('result.png')  # Save the new image.
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]